# Index of Subgroup in Alternating Group $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to show that for $n\geq 5$, the alternating group $A_n$ has no subgroup of index $p$ where $p$ prime and $p\not = n$. I am supposed to show this without using any of the Sylow theorems.

I understand that $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq5$ but I do not know how to relate this to the existence of subgroups of index $p$. I tried to show this by contradiction, assuming $H \subseteq G$ with $[G:H]=p$ and I managed to show that if this is the case, then $p<n$ but I cannot figure out anything beyond that.

Comment: Well, if you have a subgroup of index $p, you get a homomorphism  $A_n\to S_p$ coming from the action of $A_n$ on the cosets  $A_n/H$. Can this map be injective?

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess no since we could have $agH=bgH$, $a\not=b$. Is that correct? If so, what is the implication?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to avoid using Sylow's Theorem, but to use the more difficult result that $A_n$ is simple for $n \ge 5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :Let $H$ be a subgroup of index $m>1$ in $A_{n}$, $n \geq 5$. Then, the action of $A_{n}$ on $A_{n}/H$ induces a group homomorphism from $A_{n}$ to $S_{m}$ whose kenel is contained in $H$, and hence is proper! But $A_{n}$ is simple so the map is injective! Hence $\frac{n!}{2} \leq p!$...